# How can I make a Button be added when entering everything correct in the username and password?

Tags: python-3.x, pyside6, pyqt6

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QFrame

from PySide6.QtGui import QFont

class Login(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.start_ui()

    def start_ui(self):

        self.generar_formulario()

        self.show()

    def generar_formulario(self):

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        container_user = QFrame(self)

        hbox_layout_user = QHBoxLayout(container_user)

        user_label = QLabel('USUARIO: ', container_user)

        self.user_input = QLineEdit(container_user)

        font = QFont('Arial', 26)

        font.setBold(True)

        user_label.setFont(font)

        hbox_layout_user.addWidget(user_label)

        hbox_layout_user.addWidget(self.user_input)

        container_password = QFrame(self)

        hbox_layout_password = QHBoxLayout(container_password)

        password_label = QLabel('CONTRASEÑA: ', container_password)

        self.password_input = QLineEdit(container_password)

        self.password_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        

        password_label.setFont(font)

        hbox_layout_password.addWidget(password_label)

        hbox_layout_password.addWidget(self.password_input)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(container_user)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(container_password)

        self.button_validation = QPushButton('Validar', self)

        self.button_validation.clicked.connect(self.Validar_Credenciales)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.button_validation)

        

        self.resul_label = QLabel(self)

        #self.resul_label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.resul_label)

               

        

        container_user.move(50, 50)

        container_password.move(50, 150)

        self.button_validation.move(150, 250)

        self.resul_label.move(60, 350)

        

        #self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def Validar_Credenciales(self):

        usuario = "Pepe"

        password = "123"

        

        usuario_get = self.user_input.text()

        contraseña_get = self.password_input.text()

        

        if usuario_get == usuario and contraseña_get == password:

            self.resul_label.setText(f"\tBienvenido {usuario},\n  aqui tenemos recomendaciones de videos")

            self.resul_label.adjustSize()

                        

        else:

            self.resul_label.setText("Ingresa bien tu contraseña estupido")

            self.resul_label.adjustSize()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    login = Login()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I expected that when I entered everything was correct it would show me a button

Below the Label that says Welcome to the user

Comment: You should consider using QStackedWidget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the button but make it `hidden` until the password and username matches the desired values by listening for the `QLineEdit.textChanged` signal and checking the values entered into the two line edits every time the widgets contents are changed.  Then you can call `QPushButton.setHidden(False)` to show the button that was hidden.

Although I do not recommend storing user credentials in this manner... here is an example:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QFrame

from PySide6.QtGui import QFont

class Login(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_ui()

    def start_ui(self):
        self.generar_formulario()
        self.show()

    def generar_formulario(self):
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        container_user = QFrame(self)
        hbox_layout_user = QHBoxLayout(container_user)
        user_label = QLabel('USUARIO: ', container_user)
        self.user_input = QLineEdit(container_user)
        font = QFont('Arial', 26)
        font.setBold(True)
        user_label.setFont(font)
        hbox_layout_user.addWidget(user_label)
        hbox_layout_user.addWidget(self.user_input)
        container_password = QFrame(self)
        hbox_layout_password = QHBoxLayout(container_password)
        password_label = QLabel('CONTRASEÑA: ', container_password)
        self.password_input = QLineEdit(container_password)
        self.password_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        password_label.setFont(font)
        hbox_layout_password.addWidget(password_label)
        hbox_layout_password.addWidget(self.password_input)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(container_user)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(container_password)
        self.button_validation = QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.button_validation.setHidden(True)
        self.button_validation.clicked.connect(self.Validar_Credenciales)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.button_validation)
        self.resul_label = QLabel(self)
        #self.resul_label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.resul_label)
        container_user.move(50, 50)
        container_password.move(50, 150)
        self.button_validation.move(150, 250)
        self.resul_label.move(60, 350)
        self.usuario = "Pepe"
        self.password = "123"
        self.password_input.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)
        self.user_input.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)
        #self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def on_text_changed(self):
        usuario_get = self.user_input.text()
        contraseña_get = self.password_input.text()
        if usuario_get == self.usuario and contraseña_get == self.password:
            self.button_validation.setHidden(False)

    def Validar_Credenciales(self):
        usuario_get = self.user_input.text()
        contraseña_get = self.password_input.text()
        if usuario_get == self.usuario and contraseña_get == self.password:
            self.resul_label.setText(f"\tBienvenido {self.usuario},\n  aqui tenemos recomendaciones de videos")
            self.resul_label.adjustSize()
        else:
            self.resul_label.setText("Ingresa bien tu contraseña estupido")
            self.resul_label.adjustSize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thank you my king, at least you gave me a solution to hide and appear the button, well I would like to know how I can add a button when correctly entering the password And user without having to hide the button

Comment: @STE4LPHHYDR4  you could do it in the same way except for calling setHidden(False)  just construct a new button widget and place it somewhere in the window.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not something you should do. If someone left their device with username and password typed in, with apparently no way to get the password, and the button is shown, I delete the last password character, type “a”, delete the last character, type “b” and so on until the button reappears and I know the last character. Then I repeat for two characters and so on and within five minutes I have the password.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm just testing Pyside6, I'm not planning to make a login system, I'm testing its widgets